# Почему не работает время ожидания в Thread.sleep?

Tags: java, selenium

Пытаюсь создать цикл ожидания с возможностью менять время ожидания на шаг:

передано maxCountOfSleep=20;
timeToSleep = 1;

```java
    int number = 0;
    while (!(elementToWaitSelector == expectedCount) && number <= maxCountOfSleep) {
        Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
        elementToWaitSelector = driver.findElements(selectortoUpdate).size();
        number = number + 1;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что какое бы значение не передавалось в timeToSleep оно не влияет на число циклов, всегда печатается 1 и всё, при этом ожидание длится секунд 10.
Почему?

Comment: Может из за этого? `elementToWaitSelector==expectedCount`

Comment: а вообще по этому куску кода мало что мождно сказать.

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу... Вы же не ожидаете, что ожидание будет равно 1 сек?